# Is there a way to get Git Experience in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, terminal

When installing Git for Windows (https://gitforwindows.org/) one can choose between "Use MinTTY (the default terminal of MSYS2)" or "Use Windows' default console window". [Git for Windows Installation Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR5VV.png)

Say i'd like to use PowerShell, can i somehow get a similar git representation here e.g. see the current branch in Powershell? (... and all the other information which is hided in the local .git folder)

I'm using Git for Windows 2.25.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Posh git" does exactly that :

https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

The installation instructions (on the landing page) detail how you should set up your Powershell environment to load it on each shell start :

[Posh git: Installation](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installation)